# How do i run a .sh file on startup (ubuntu server)

Tags: server, minecraft

How do i run a file named start.sh file on startup if im on ubuntu server? i decided to install ubuntu server on a pc that i rarely use so i can have my minecraft server on it ... and i want to be able to add plugins and such on it without having to go to that computer all the time (switch screens and such) and just use ftp and transfer all of the files that way and then restart my computer then the new plugins are loaded. can someone please help me with this? :)

(sorry if this was confusing its really late here atm)

Answer (score 0):

Copy everything in the script (excluding `#!/bin/xxxx`) into `/etc/rc.local`.

You may need to run:

```
systemctl enable rc-local.service
```

Easy!

Comment: Are you sure that rc.local is executed by default since the switch to systemd? Would you also have to run `systemctl enable rc-local.service`, or is it set up by default?

Comment: Am i supposed to make that file? cuz i dont have one ... and what if i want the server to start on start up and show me whatever its loading and allow me to type in commands for the server?

Comment: Please open a new question on how to create the file.